# Paste IF value in target

Tags: excel, vba, paste, formulas

I want to create a macro to copy a range (C2:C22) where there are formulas and paste it on column range (D2:D22) as values. My problem is that every 6 cells I have a formula and I don't want the macro to override it. 
I have been trying with this macro, but it doesn't copy formulas, only values and I need to paste on values, not on formulas.

Thanks!

```
Sub example()
    Dim source As Range
    Dim target As Range
    Set source = ActiveSheet.Range("c2:c22")
    Set target = ActiveSheet.Range("d2:d22")
    copy_formulas source:=source, target:=target

End Sub

Public Sub copy_formulas(source As Range, target As Range)
    'Assumes that all formulas start with '=' and all non formulas do not
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim c As Range

    For i = 1 To source.Rows.Count
        For j = 1 To source.Columns.Count
            Set c = source(RowIndex:=i, ColumnIndex:=j)
            If Left(c.Formula, 1) <> "=" Then
                target(RowIndex:=i, ColumnIndex:=j).Value = c.Value
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Your question says:
"I have been trying with this macro, but it doesn't copy formulas, only values and I need to paste on values, not on formulas."
which sounds like it's doing what you need it to.  Can you clarify?

Comment: @ChrisMoore OP is trying to copy values without overwriting existing formulas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the inside of your loop to:

```
Set c = target(RowIndex:=i, ColumnIndex:=j)
If Left(c.Formula, 1) <> "=" Then
    c.Value = source(RowIndex:=i, ColumnIndex:=j).Value
End If
```

Your current code is testing whether there is a formula in the **source** cell, but your question implies that you should be testing for a formula in the **target** cell.

Comment: Making wrong code look wrong 101: `c` is a terrible identifier - this bug wouldn't have happened if `c` was named `targetCell` instead ...assuming `Set targetCell = source(...)` looks wrong enough

Comment: Thank you so much. I was really stuck! You solve my issue :)

Answer (score 0):

This loop might be more efficient:

```
Dim rSource As Range
Dim rTarget As Range
Set rSource = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C2:C22")
Set rTarget = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D2:D22")
For Item = 1 To rSource.Count
   If Not rTarget.Cells(Item).HasFormula Then
      rTarget.Cells(Item).Value = rSource.Cells(Item).Value
   End If
Next Item
```

Comment: Thank you Tony, I really appreciate it :)

Comment: how can I add multiple ranges to this loop? I tried the below but it only copy/paste the first range Z18:AA250 - AU18:AV250

Dim rSource As Range
Dim rTarget As Range
Set rSource = ActiveSheet.Range("Z18:AA250,W18:X250,H18:H250,O18:O250")
Set rTarget = ActiveSheet.Range("AU18:AV250,AX18:AY250,AR18:AR250,AS18:AS250")
For Item = 1 To rSource.Count
   If Not rTarget.Cells(Item).HasFormula Then
      rTarget.Cells(Item).Value = rSource.Cells(Item).Value
   End If
Next Item